# how to give regExp in object,for password,for me it not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I have used regExp in my app,this exp taken from json obj,but it is not working for password and zip code particularly.
for password and zip code given like this,

```
'pwd': {
        "exp": /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=(.*[a-z]){1,})(?=(.*[\d]){1,})(?=(.*[\W_]){1,})(?!.*\s).{8,}$/
    },
    'zip_code': {
        'exp': /^([0-9]*)$/
    },
```

Comment: Add complete code. Is JSON coming from server?

Comment: no,created as constant file,taking from that file.

Comment: How do you execute the regex? What's your *assumption* about these regexes, what should they do?

Comment: sorry i did small mistake,instead of ng-pattern I used only pattern.now working fine.thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know your Intention (Input OR Output)

BTW, Try **HTML 5** Validations

Put your Regex Pattern within the '**pattern**' attribute; Like this:

```html
<form>
  Country code: <input pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**More Info** at:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp